# "Provider error" when saving the edits done to layer in GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, editing, error, geopackage, save

By means of the QGIS 3.16.3 I have created a GeoPackage with two layers, a point layer and a polygon layer.

The point layer is named "pt", with attributes: `geometry, sN, sE, sS, sW, uuid`.

The polygon layer is named "crown", with attributes: `geometry, pt_uuid`.

I can add a point to "pt" or a polygon to "crown", but cannot save the layer edits. I get the following error:

> Could not commit changes to layer pt
> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
> Provider errors:
> OGR error creating feature -35: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO "pt" ( "geometry", "sN", "sE", "sS", "sW", "uuid") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably `uuid` is the 'unique' identifier. Is it actually unique? If it is not, then writing will fail. Perhaps the features you are adding are attempting to use a value that has already been used.

Comment: Hi Matt. "uuid" is unique.